# Stretch div according to another one

Tags: html, css, position

I have the following code:

```
#left {
width:383px;
margin:0px;
float: left;
position:relative;
}
.bg_top{
background: transparent url(../bg_top.png) no-repeat;
width: 383px;
height: 140px;
}
.bg_middle{
background: transparent url(../bg_middle.png) no-repeat;
width: 383px;
height: 100%;
}
.bg_bottom{
background: transparent url(../bg_bottom.png) no-repeat;
width: 383px;
height: 131px;
}
#left_inner{
width:375px;
border:2px solid #98b73f;
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
}

<div id='wrap'>
    <div id='left'>
        <div class='bg_top'>
            bg_top
        </div>
        <div class='bg_middle'>
            bg_middle
        </div>
        <div class='bg_bottom'>
            bg_bottom
        </div>
        <div id='left_inner'>
<p>long text</p></div</div</div>
```

I want the `bg_middle` class to stretch to the height of the `left_inner` `div`. I have tried with height 100% and searched the net for answers. I'm new in the world of css. I think I have to connect the 3 `div`s that are the background to the inner `div` somehow...

Answer (score 0):

With the HTML as is it  you can't do it without Javascript. Block elements adjust in height to their container. Si if the goal is to use a `background-image` just apply it to the `left-inner`. Don't use position absolute 'cause that block would postion itself indepent from the content flow.
Given that you have fixed heights you can use `min-height` in case there's not enough content.
I'm not sure this is what you're looking for.

Comment: yes but the image is changing... that's why i have to use 3 images. The top and the bottom of the image are different...

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to do something different here..
However this is the solution I suggest with the original approach:

```
#left {
 width:383px;
 margin:0px;
 position: relative;
 }

.bg_bottom{
  background: transparent url(../bg_bottom.png) no-repeat;

  height: 131px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1
 }

.bg_top{
  background: transparent url(../bg_top.png) no-repeat;

  height: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1
 }
.bg_middle{
 height: 100%; /* it does work*/
 background: transparent url(../bg_middle.png) repeat top left;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -2;
}
```

`height= 100%` works if the parents (or at least one) have a height (100% of 0 is 0).
You can cascade starting with the html

```
html, body{height: 100%;}
```

Or you can just give the `#left` a `height` or `min-height`

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all,

Last night I found a way around this. This is my final approach, it still needs some small adjustments, but it works (for now).

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main">
<div class='bg_top'></div>
<div class='bg_middle'>
<div>LONG LONG TEXT</div>
</div>
<div class='bg_bottom'></div>
</div>

#wrap{
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.bg_top{
    background: transparent url(../bg_top.png) no-repeat;
    height: 140px;
}
.bg_middle{
    background: transparent url(../bg_middle.png) repeat;
}
.bg_middle div{
    margin:-130px 10px -100px 10px;
    border:1.5px solid #98b73f;
}
.bg_bottom{
    background: transparent url(../bg_bottom.png) no-repeat;
    height: 131px;
}
#main {
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    margin-left:0px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Thanks @Maroshii for the reply. I will also try your approach, but for now I'll stick to this. Hope I will not have to change a lot for browser compatibility :)